# why chain.from_iterable does not iterate over int list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

why `chain.from_iterable` gives error if argument given to it is `sus(7)` which is a list of integers instead it works perfectly fine when `[sus(7)]` is passed to it.

```
import itertools as p

def sus(n):

    a = []
    for i in range(n):
        a.append(i)
    return a

print(sus(7))

for i in p.chain(sus(7)):
    print('a1',i)
for i in p.chain.from_iterable(sus(7)):
    print('a2',i)
```

Comment: Because it takes an iterable of iterables, and a list of ints is an iterable of ints, and ints are not iterable. Looking at the documentation’s example correct use of `itertools.chain.from_iterable` might help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I get it.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source of chain.from_iterable:

```
def from_iterable(iterables):
# chain.from_iterable(['ABC', 'DEF']) --> A B C D E F
    for it in iterables:
        for element in it:
            yield element
```

You can see that it expects an iterable, such as a list, of iterables. This works fine if you have, e.g., a list of strings. However, if your list elements cannot be iterated over, and that applies to any numeric value such as an int, it will throw the error you got.

Comment: That's not the source code of `chain.from_iterable`; that's an example Python implementation of equivalent functionality.

Comment: Ok but I got it from the docs at  https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable

Comment: @PaulaThomas https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c

Comment: @PaulaThomas: The docs say `chain.from_iterable` is *roughly equivalent to* that Python function, not that that's the actual implementation.